# Ruby - How to use the method parameter as the name of the variable?

Tags: ruby

How would I use the parameter value as the instance variable name of an object?

This is the object

```
Class MyClass    
    def initialize(ex,ey)
      @myvar = ex
      @myothervar = ey
    end
end
```

I have the following method

```
def test(element)
  instanceofMyClass.element  #this obviously doesnt work
end
```

How can I have the test method return either myvar or myothervar value depending on the element parameter. I don't want to write an if condition though, I want to pass myvar or myother var via element to the object instance if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def test(element)
  instanceofMyClass.send(element.to_sym)  
end
```

You'll get a missing method error if instanceofMyClass doesn't respond to element.

Comment: To be clear about the difference between EmFi's method and mine: This one requires you to have a reader method for the instance variable and goes through that while mine accesses it directly.

Comment: Perfect, thank you all  "instanceofMyClass.send(element)"  does it beautifully. Since I already have a reader, this one seems to be the cleanest/easiest.

Comment: I included the to_sym to help ensure that a proper method missing error is generated, in the event the argument of element doesn't evaluate to a string.

Answer (score 3):

```
def test(element)
  instanceofmyclass.instance_variable_get element
end

test :@myvar # => ex
test :@myothervar # => ey
```

Comment: I think this one is the nice clean one.

Comment: To be perfectly honest, I'd use `send` if we're talking a public property (as EmFi's case assumes) — that way, we play nice with overrides. This is just more of a general answer to the question asked, which was about instance variables in general.

Answer (score 0):

I like the simplicity of `send()`, though one bad thing with it is that it can be used to access privates. The issue is still remains solution below, but at least then it's explicitly specified, and reader can see which methods are to be forwarded. The first one just uses delegation, while the second one uses more dynamic way to define methods on the fly.

```
require 'forwardable'
class A
  extend Forwardable
  def_delegators :@myinstance, :foo, :bar

  class B
    def foo
      puts 'foo called'
    end

    def bar
      puts 'bar called'
    end

    def quux
      puts 'quux called'
    end

    def bif
      puts 'bif called'
    end
  end

  def initialize
    @myinstance = B.new
  end

  %i(quux bif).each do |meth| # note that only A#quux and A#bif are defined dynamically
    define_method meth do |*args_but_we_do_not_have_any|
      @myinstance.send(meth)
    end
  end
end

a = A.new

a.foo
a.bar

a.quux
a.bif
```